# Django form not saving email

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

My views-

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .AuthForms import registerUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
def registerUsers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ucf = registerUserForm(request.POST)
        if ucf.is_valid():
            ucf.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username = ucf.cleaned_data['username'], password = ucf.cleaned_data['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('content')
    else:
        ucf = registerUserForm()

    return render(request, 'LoginAndSignUp/SignUpPage.html', {'ucf': ucf})
```

My form -

I have extended the usercreationform

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm , PasswordResetForm
from django import forms 
class registerUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email', 'autocomplete':'off'}))
    username = forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Username','autocomplete':'off',}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}))
    password2 = None

    class meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1']

class userLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Username','autocomplete':'off'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}))


class userPasswordResetEmailForm(PasswordResetForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your email', 'autocomplete':'off',}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is my template. I suppose everything is correct but still its not saving the email

```
<form novalidate action="" method="post">
{%csrf_token%}


<div class="fieldWrapper">
{{ucf.email.errors}}
{{ucf.email}}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
{{ucf.username.errors}}
{{ucf.username}}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
{{ucf.password1.errors}}
{{ucf.password1}}
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom: 4%;">
<span class="director">Already with us? <a href="{%url 'login'%}">Log In</a></span>
<div class="director">
    <a href="{%url 'content'%}"><i class="fa fa-compass"></i> Explore anonymously</a>
</div>
</div>
<button class="primaryButton" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

The email field is not saving the email to database wherease the username and password is correctly being saved. Someone please help

Comment: Before calling ucf.is_valid(), does ucf.data contains a value for email?

Comment: @Vincent No it doesn't contains. I am confused because the values of username and password are saving without any problem. And also I had deleted the previous version in which I used the same method and the form was saving everything correctly.

Comment: Can you show the the html of the form you use.

Comment: @Vincent Yes I have edited the question you can see

Comment: Do you use javascript to trigger the form submit? I see there is no action for the form.

Comment: @Vincent No, why would I use js for form submit? And I think action is not needed to submit a form besides the username and password are saving correctly

Comment: Its not necessary indeed if both the rendering and submitting of the form is on the same url. That's probably the case for you.

Comment: Do you have any fix ? I am really stressed

Comment: If I test your setup, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right database column? auth_user and is the emailaddress you enter correct? Try debugging ucf and see what data it contains. Also you can try to create a new app just to see if the basics of this user registration works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. I recreated your project and it works as intended. username, password and email are saved to the auth_user table. This is what mine looks like:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    // other urls
    path('users/', register_users, name='create_user')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

from users.forms import RegisterUserForm


def register_users(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ucf = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        if ucf.is_valid():
            ucf.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=ucf.cleaned_data['username'], password=ucf.cleaned_data['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('content')
    else:
        ucf = RegisterUserForm()

    return render(request, 'users/sign_up_page.html', {'ucf': ucf})
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms


class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'autocomplete': 'off'}))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username', 'autocomplete': 'off'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1']
```

sign_up_page.html

```
<form novalidate action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}


    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ ucf.email.errors }}
        {{ ucf.email }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ ucf.username.errors }}
        {{ ucf.username }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ ucf.password1.errors }}
        {{ ucf.password1 }}
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 4%;">
{#        <span class="director">Already with us? <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a></span>#}
        <div class="director">
{#            <a href="{% url 'content' %}"><i class="fa fa-compass"></i> Explore anonymously</a>#}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="primaryButton" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Very hard to tell. Try creating a new app and adding just the files of my answer and see if it works.

Comment: Yes I think that's the only option left. Anyways thank you for efforts